# How to deal with multiple facts in dimensional modelling

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have a scenario where the technical team is requesting for single dimensional model combining  different subject areas like finance, sales,etc.

eg: Fact table 1 -> Finance area gives P&L heads at month level

| Month | P&L Head | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | Net Sales | 100 Mn |
| 2023-04-01 | Throughput | 80 Mn |
| 2023-04-01 | EBITDA | 20 Mn |
| 2023-04-01 | PBT | 5 Mn |

Fact table 2 -> Sales area gives monthly sales by product, customer

| Month | Product | Customer | Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | ABC | C1 | 2 Mn |
| 2023-04-01 | ABC | C2 | 3 Mn |
| 2023-04-01 | XYZ | C3 | 1 Mn |
| 2023-04-01 | XYZ | C1 | 2 Mn |

3 Dimensions noted : Time, Product, Customer

2 Fact Measures noted : Sales Amount, P&L Head Amount

My query is
Is it advisable to create single data model or keep them separate as per data modelling best practices

1. Keeping only Time dimension (Conformed dimension) in the common fact and all measures aggregated

| Month | Net Sales Amount | Throughput Amount | EBITDA Amount | PBT Amount | Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | 100 | 80 | 20 | 5 | 8 |

2. Keeping all dimensions but the rows where dimension is not available to leave it blank

| Month | Product | Customer | P&L Head | P&L Amount | Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | ABC | C1 | x | x | 2 |
| 2023-04-01 | ABC | C2 | x | x | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 | XYZ | C3 | x | x | 1 |
| 2023-04-01 | XYZ | C1 | x | x | 2 |
| 2023-04-01 | x | Net Sales | 100 | x | x |
| 2023-04-01 | x | Throughput | 80 | x | x |
| 2023-04-01 | x | EBITDA | 20 | x | x |
| 2023-04-01 | x | PBT | 5 | x | x |

3. Keep both data models separate

Star schema 1 -> for P&L data
Star schema 2 -> for Sales data

Which of the above 3 are correct...
Thankyou in advance.

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

A fact table needs to have its grain defined and then all measures must adhere to that grain. So if you wanted a single fact table then only your first option (having date as the only dimension) is a possibility.

I'm guessing that you have other reporting requirements that will involve these measures so you're going to need separate fact tables anyway. Whether you also need to build this single fact table is a cost-benefit decision only you can make: is the cost of creating and maintaining this additional fact table outweighed by the benefit of being able to query a single table v. querying multiple tables and combining the results